# Oracle merge adding records when matched

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, merge

I have a table that has an ID field with a trigger (so it's essentially an IDENTITY field) as my primary key.  I mostly don't care about that.

The rest of the data are several linking keys, and I want to query my data, and if any of those keys have changed, add a new record with a new effective date.  If all the keys are the same, then nothing should be added.

However, even when all of the keys match, it is adding new records.  All of the fields I care about are exactly the same, so I'm essentially getting duplicate records, but with a new ID and new effective date.

I'll simplify my code a bit, but this is essentially what I have:

```
MERGE_TABLE (
merge_ID  NUMBER(18) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
asof_Date  Date,
keyA  varchar2(10 byte),
keyB  varchar2(10 byte),
keyC  varchar2(10 byte),
table_date Date)
```

There is a trigger on merge_ID on insert to use a sequence.

```
MERGE INTO merge_table mt
USING (
    select keyA, keyB, keyC, table_date
    from table  -- it's actually a complex query, but it's getting data
      ) tbl
ON (rtrim(tbl.keyA) = rtrim(mt.keyA)
   AND rtrim(tbl.keyB) = rtrim(mt.keyB) 
   AND rtrim(tbl.keyC) = rtrim(mt.keyC))
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (asof_Date, keyA, keyB, keyC, table_date)
   VALUES (sysdate, tbl.keyA, tbl.keyB, tbl.keyC, tbl.table_date)
```

If my MERGE_TABLE starts with the following data:

```
merge_ID    asof_Date   keyA   keyB   keyC  table_date
  10        1/1/2018    333    456    987    12/31/2017
  11        1/1/2018    444    234    876    12/31/2017
  12        1/1/2018    222    789    654    12/31/2017
```

then, after running it, I have the following data:

```
merge_ID    asof_Date   keyA   keyB   keyC  table_date
  10        1/1/2018    333    456    987    12/31/2017
  11        1/1/2018    444    234    876    12/31/2017
  12        1/1/2018    222    789    654    12/31/2017
  13        3/22/2018   333    456    987    12/31/2017
  14        3/22/2018   444    234    876    12/31/2017
  15        3/22/2018   222    789    654    12/31/2017
```

My keys all matched, but it did an insert anyway.  Why?

If KeyB had changed on the first record from 456 to 678, the data I would want is:

```
merge_ID    asof_Date   keyA   keyB   keyC  table_date
  10        1/1/2018    333    456    987    12/31/2017
  11        1/1/2018    444    234    876    12/31/2017
  12        1/1/2018    222    789    654    12/31/2017
  13        3/22/2018   333    678    987    12/31/2017
```

Comment: Since you're storing numbers as strings (`VARCHAR2`) it's worth checking to see if you have trailing spaces or something like that. Try replacing the `ON` clause in your merge with `ON ( TRIM(tbl.keyA) = TRIM(mt.keyA) AND TRIM(tbl.keyB) = TRIM(mt.keyB) AND TRIM(tbl.keyC) = TRIM(mt.keyC) )`. If that doesn't work, then maybe try with `TO_NUMBER()`. And if that doesn't work, there are ways to convert strings to numbers safely in Oracle.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to save typing, and I thought of that and put a RTRIM() around everything in the compare.  I'll go update my question, since that is valid, and I should have put it in.

Comment: You could have leading spaces as well - `TRIM()` is better in this situation than `RTRIM()`

Comment: My hopes were high, and then were dashed.  TRIM() doesn't fix it.  However, I will leave that in, since that is a good point.

Comment: Just tried your SQL, I don't have inserted duplicate rows. Can you check the inner SQL output (with value wrappers to trap special chars, if any). Plus, since these are numbers anyway, why not use the numeric type?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that there are invisible control characters or whitespace (tab, newline, etc.).

Comment: @access_granted - I'm using the type of the underlying data, and that's not something I have control of.

Comment: @DavidFaber - those keys are used all over the place in existing software, so that doesn't seem likely.  Nonetheless, it's worth a try.  It's kind of encouraging that it is working properly for you - it looked right.

Comment: instead of rtrim() try to_number() for matching

Comment: Instead of Merge, convert the SQL into SELECT and check if the records are indeed matching.

Comment: I would remove the trim/rtrim calls as they mean you cannot use normal indexes and they are making the code harder to read. Rather I would add a unique constraint on the key columns. Then the insert will fail if it is about to create a duplicate and you can use MERGE ... LOG ERRORS INTO (https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dml-error-logging-10gr2#merge) for finding the bad records.

Comment: Try dump the columns to see the characters. SELECT DUMP('key_b', 1017) from table;

Comment: @ArtBajji - it is nulls!  I didn't mention that there are some key records that are null, because I didn't think it was important.  But by selecting and comparing, I see that the blank key records don't match, and thus, they are being added.  I simplified my problem too much, and yet you all still helped me.

Comment: If anyone makes an answer saying if any of the key records are null that the matching I have won't work, I will accept that answer.  (I haven't verified that works, but I really think it is it.)